# Tag selected files in Finder with single keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut, finder-tag

It's been well covered how to create a keyboard shortcut for the Tags... menu option in Finder. What I want is a way to tag selected files or folders with a single keyboard shortcut. The same shortcut should untag them.

Comment: **Where** has it been well covered how to create a keyboard shortcut for tags??  *This* question is the one I arrive at from a site search looking for that information.  Could you please provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the OS X built-in Automator and the great [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) command-line utility.

1. Create a new Service that accepts selected files/folders from Finder (follow the steps [here](https://superuser.com/a/596271/150881))
2. In Run Shell Script, select "Pass input:" as `arguments` and use the following code:

   ```
   TAG="Red"
   tag="/usr/local/bin/tag"

   for filename in "$@"
   do
     if $tag --list --no-name "$filename" | grep "$TAG\b"; then
       $tag --remove "$TAG" "$filename"
     else
       $tag --add "$TAG" "$filename"
     fi
   done
   ```

   replacing the value of `TAG` with the name of the tag you want to use and `tag` with the location where *tag* is installed (the one above should be default for *brew*).
3. Assign a shortcut to this service in the System Settings.

The script simply checks for each file whether it is already tagged with the given tag, and removes or adds the tag to switch it. You can go fancier from here.